# Can't use {{ form.media }} in django-datetime-widget because my model contain field named "media"

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm trying to use django-datetime-widget with my ModelForm to show date/time picker.

github repo:
https://github.com/asaglimbeni/django-datetime-widget

I followed instructions up to here:

```
<head>
....
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    {{ form.media }}

....
</head>
```

But my model have field named "media", which is declared in my models.py like this:

```
media = models.ImageField(blank=True, 
            null=True, 
            upload_to=media_location,
            default=settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '/images/default_icon.png',
            storage=FileSystemStorage(location=settings.MEDIA_ROOT))
```

My 'media' field is used to enable user to upload an image of a product.

Problem:
When I put `{{ form.media }}` in `<head>` tag in template, it just render the image uploader form. Clearly it does not do its job in django-datetime-widget integration.

P.S. I'm not sure if renaming the 'media' field will serious break my production website. This 'media' field is used to store 1,000+ important images of my users.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't rename the field, then you could write a [custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters) that returns the form's media.

```
@register.filter
def media(form):
    return form.media
```

Then load the filter in your template, and change the line to `{{ form|media }}`

Comment: Hi. Thanks. Let me try this out and will report back the result. /cheers